# polidea ble encode send package to base64

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, base64, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to send a command to my scooter via [polidea ble](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) but I don't know how to compose the package and encode it to base64, I tried different ways but it seems it does not work. Here is the documentation of how I need to make the package:

```
APP  Bluetooth
START_PACK, OPCODESEND, LENGTH, D0, CHECKSUM                  (START_PACK = 0x55)
OPCODESEND
0x02 – Speed Limit
    D0 – 1 is 6Km/k, 2 is 12Km/h, 3 is 20Km/h, 4 is 25Km/h, 5 No speed Limit
0x03 - Change Zero Start 
    D0  0 Zero Start OFF, 1 Zero Start ON
0x05 –Lock Unlock Scooter
    D0  0 Unlock, 1 Lock
0x06 – On/Off light from display
    D0  0 light OFF, 1 light ON
```

For example, how should the package look to turn on the light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the documentation you have included, is that to turn on the light the code to create the packet in base64 would be:

```js
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

var start_pack = 0x55;
var opcode = 0x06 // light
var action = 0x01 // On
var length = 0x01 // Length of what? action?
var checksum = start_pack + opcode + action + length

var valueBytes = Buffer.alloc(5);
valueBytes[0] = start_pack;
valueBytes[1] = opcode;
valueBytes[2] = length;
valueBytes[3] = action;
valueBytes[4] = checksum;
var valueBase64 = valueBytes.toString('base64')
console.log("Data to write: " + valueBase64)
```

This gave me an output of:

```
Data to write: VQYBAV0=
```

Comment: great, it's working, lenght it's 5 the lenght of the package. Thank you!